# QGIS: Unable to add a new feature when joining two PostGIS tables

Tags: qgis

I have two Postgresql tables: parent and child, as the following:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE public.parent_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE public.parent
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.parent_id_seq'::regclass),
    type character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT parent_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE public.child_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE public.child
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.child_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    parent_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT child_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT child_parent_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
        REFERENCES public.parent (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

In QGIS I have made a join between these two tables (as shown in the attached image). But I am not able to add new features from the attribute table. When I do so I got the following error:

```
Could not commit changes to layer child

Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.

  Provider errors:
      PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "nextval('public.parent_id_seq'::regclass)"
    LINE 1: ...ild"("id","name","parent_id") VALUES ($1,'name 9','nextval('...
```

**How to Reproduce**

1- Create these two tables, as described above.

2- Add them to QGIS.

3- Right click on the parent table, then select properties, then from the Joins tab create a new Join as shown in the attached screen shot.

4- Then allow editing both layers.

5- After that open the attribute table of the parent layer, then select Add Feature, and fill in the type and name fields.

6- Save the parent layer, it will be saved with no problems. Then save the child layer, it will generate the error mentioned above.

I am using QGIS 3.10

[image]

Comment: That isn't the way to add the postgres relation to QGIS. Why do you want to join the tables?

Comment: the error message indicates that the `id` and `parent_id` are swapped. The sequence should populate `child.id` and `$1` should be the `parent_id`

Comment: @JGH `$1` is the value of the `child_id_sequence`. When the _parent_ table is saved, another (maybe `$1`) value is stored in the `parent.id` field, but the _child_ table don't know it and try to store the default `nextval('public.parent_id_seq'::regclass)` value in its `parent_id` field.

Comment: ... but it is not the default for this field!

Comment: yes it is, in the join he/she is making it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101662/discussion-between-gabriel-de-luca-and-jgh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the tables are defined, there is a one-to-many relation between them. You must include that relation in the *Project Properties*, in the *Relations* tab.

[image: 1]

You can *Discover Relations* to automatically define it from the PostgreSQL source connection.

---

In the *Data Source* tab of the *Project Properties* tick on the options: *Automatically create transaction groups when possible* and *Evaluate default values on the provider side*.

[image: 2]

Related tables will be saved and edited as a group. And the sequences will be evaluated by the PostgreSQL server.

---

Now you can start creating features in the *parent* layer and in the *child* layer. The forms are fully customizable. If you want to create a new *child* feature which *parent* feature is not already created, you can tick on the *Allow adding new features* option, in the *parent_id* widget, from the *Attributes Form* of the *Layer Properties*.

[image: 3]

I define the *Drag and drop designer* type to order the *parent_id* widget before the *name* widget. I also modify the *parent_id* widget to show *type* value instead of *id* value. The value stored is an integer, I am just seeing it as the *type* string in the *Attribute Form*. It includes the attribute table, the identify form and the create new feature form.

---

Now, when you create a *child* feature you can create a *parent* feature instead of choose one.

[image: 4]

---

To see a joined table, there are many ways. I just like the way that *Virtual layers* are refreshed:

```sql
SELECT p.type, c.name
FROM parent p
INNER JOIN child c
ON p.id = c.parent_id;
```

[image: 5]

---

References:

- https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-one-or-many-to-many-relations
- https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#attributes-form-properties
- https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed reply. Actually the reason for joining these two tables is that the relation between them is one-to-one, and I want to be able to view/add/update/delete the two related records using one screen (the attribute table screen of the parent).

Comment: @devfaz A one-to-one realtion is defined with a `UNIQUE` constraint in the _foreign key_. You can View/Add/Update/Delete records of related tables from a Form, maybe you want an unified form to manage two tables. Trying to edit features of the child table from the parent table is just not the way to do it, I don't know if the default value inconsistency created can be solved.

Comment: @gebriel de luca, how to create a unified form to manage the two tables?

Comment: @devfaz I don't know it, I like to have one form for each table. But you can ask it in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that QGIS uses the default value for `parent.id`, which is not a numerical value but instead the call to the sequence. When saving the `parent` table, this expression is translated to a number and everything is fine.

When saving the child table, QGIS did not yet accessed the updated `parent.id` value, but instead is still using the default expression (`nextval('public.parent_id_seq'::regclass)`), which fails.

In fact, looking at the logs (PostGIS tab), we can see that QGIS has some issues to even display the data for the new record, tryind to query on `... WHERE ("parent_id" = 'nextval(''parent_id_seq''::regclass)')`

```
WARNING    1 cursor states lost.
SQL: DECLARE qgis_56 BINARY CURSOR FOR SELECT "id","parent_id"::text FROM "public"."child" WHERE ("parent_id" = 'nextval(''parent_id_seq''::regclass)') LIMIT 1
Result: 7 (ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "nextval('parent_id_seq'::regclass)"
LINE 1: ...::text FROM "public"."child" WHERE ("parent_id" = 'nextval('...
```

One option is to populate the parent data, save the table (which changes the parent.id to a number) then populate the child table and save it. To see the updated child data (id) you may want to un-select the option `cache join layer in a virtual layer`. It is a pain to do with many back and forth between editing/saving and it is error prone. The solution provided by @Gabriel De Luca (editing 2 tables separately) is much simpler.

Another option is to manually write the `parent.id` value, populate fields for both the parent and child table, and at last save both tables. A big issue is that you need to reset the parent_id sequence when you are done.

There is a third option that will makes editing very easy but it harder to set-up is to create a view in Postgres doing the join between the two tables, then to set `instead of` triggers for add/edit/delete on the view, which propagate the changes to the underlying tables. You would work with this view in Qgis as if it was a regular layer